# How do I rig a game asset for a state change? (Armoured/Normal/Damaged)

Tags: rigging, unity

I'm looking for a workflow...

I have a small tank mesh that I'm about to rig.

The game I'd like to create with it (in Unity) will require it to be either Armoured, normal, or damaged.  It may also require LODs.

What I'd like is to hide or unhide the different states of the tank, but still use the minimum number of bones.  For example: The turret that turns uses one bone, but has the normal mesh unhidden, and the armoured and damaged meshes hidden, with all turret's different mesh states using the same bone.

I'm planning that the meshes can be unhidden or hidden when needed in Unity depending on the situation.

With all that in mind I'd like to rig this tank properly in Blender so that it's Unity-ready.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Here's what I understand already:

- Unity only imports bones and blend shapes from a rig. All other modifiers are ignored, so don't use them.
- LODs require a name change for Unity to automatically register them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say (without knowing fizzle about Unity) that your best shot would be shape keys, but...

If I had to do it with a bone in blender animating, I'd try driving object visibility or material transparency by a bone's position/rotation with a greater-than statement.

Working from my knowledge of the BGE which may or may not be similar to Unity (I have a DeLorion), I'd say you should have a script switch out the meshes based on the bone.

Cute tank BTW.

Comment: I know next to fizzle about Unity myself (a handy unit of measurement when talking about knowledge).

I never thought of using a blend shape as a state change.  That's actually genius.  I'll give it a go.  Thank you!   And... thanks for the nice words about my tank.  :)